# Check overlap by each ID, SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, overlap

I am trying to find a solution how to find overlap in case below.

I have two tables with employee ID, number or breaktime, hour of planned breaktime start and stop.  In ideal situation number of planned break and used should be the same but it is not. What I need to do is compare by each ID and check if used break is in the same time like planned, if not how big is the gap.

My idea is to check by ID each number with every number in the second table and mark it ok/not ok an how big is the gap. I thin there is a better way, more efficient to do this. Could You help me to find the solution?

I'll appreciate every prompt.

```
ID   | number | time_start_plan         | time_stop_plan
-----+--------+-------------------------+------------------------
965  |  1     | 2017-09-11 00:00:00.000 | 2017-09-11 00:15:00.000  
965  |  2     | 2017-09-11 01:15:00.000 | 2017-09-11 01:25:00.000  
965  |  3     | 2017-09-11 02:40:00.000 | 2017-09-11 02:50:00.000  
965  |  4     | 2017-09-11 04:20:00.000 | 2017-09-11 04:30:00.000  
1122 |  1     | 2017-09-11 00:05:00.000 | 2017-09-11 00:20:00.000  
1122 |  2     | 2017-09-11 01:20:00.000 | 2017-09-11 01:30:00.000  
1122 |  3     | 2017-09-11 03:10:00.000 | 2017-09-11 03:20:00.000 

ID   | number | time_start_used         | time_stop_used
-----+--------+-------------------------+------------------------
965  | 1      | 2017-09-11 00:34:41.000 | 2017-09-11 00:36:34.000  
965  | 2      | 2017-09-11 02:33:00.000 | 2017-09-11 02:36:26.000  
965  | 3      | 2017-09-11 04:24:17.000 | 2017-09-11 04:27:42.000  
965  | 4      | 2017-09-11 06:06:02.000 | 2017-09-11 06:18:19.000  
965  | 5      | 2017-09-11 22:41:02.000 | 2017-09-11 22:42:06.000  
1122 | 1      | 2017-09-11 00:15:12.000 | 2017-09-11 00:15:32.000  
1122 | 2      | 2017-09-11 01:07:56.000 | 2017-09-11 01:26:57.000  
1122 | 3      | 2017-09-11 01:49:02.000 | 2017-09-11 01:51:13.000  
1122 | 4      | 2017-09-11 03:33:50.000 | 2017-09-11 03:34:17.000  
1122 | 5      | 2017-09-11 04:07:59.000 | 2017-09-11 04:09:10.000  
1122 | 6      | 2017-09-11 05:51:23.000 | 2017-09-11 05:54:22.000
```

Comment: what do you mean by gap? Is it a time difference (number of minutes/hours) ignoring the actual start and end time stamp vs planned once?

Comment: Sorry, I need to clarify. I mean time difference, for example:                      
2017-09-11 01:15:00.000 - 2017-09-11 02:33:00.000 is 78 minutes difference, I need rows where it will be more than 5 minutes, I will check them why it is bigger than expected.

Comment: So you mean, even if start and stop date/time vary from planned vs actual but if time varies then out put as not OK? for ex:- Id = 965 and number = 1 both start and stop time are different. In this case you want to display as Not Ok. right?

Comment: Yes, to be precise, I want ot compare timeline, for example:   id 995 number 1 starts at 00:00 and end 00:15  form table one and compare it with every timelines in table two with ID 995. I want to know which break is equal an which one isn't and how big is the difference.

Comment: I'd probably focus on the abs datediff of the start time, in minutes.  You could start from the planned breaks, and join to that any real breaks within an acceptable number of minutes.

Comment: If id 965 number 1 from table1 has to be compared with table of ID 965 it never matched since the time in second table has seconds where as table1 do not.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of the output you would like to see based on this sample data?

Comment: I'll try to describe main idea of this task. What I need to do is: compare timelines by ID, what I want to prove is that employee went on break on correct time (or not). If corret output will be f.eg 'ok' if not haow big is the dofference in seconds. I suppose only this two outputs will be enough to me.

Comment: One important thing column number its just a number of break, pleae do not treat it like somethin by which we need compare (1 to 1, 2 to 2), break from first table could have a few matching rows from second table. This is teh reason why I want compare one row from first one with every rows(the same ID) from the second.

Answer (score 1):

This solution variant only partially matching [number] in that the t1.number must be <= to the t2.number. This leads of course to many more rows of output.

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e7140/12) as a demonstration.

**Query**:

```
select
       coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) ids
     , coalesce(t1.number, t2.number) numbers
     , datediff(minute,t1.time_start_plan, t2.time_start_used) diff_start
     , datediff(minute,t1.time_stop_plan, t2.time_stop_used) diff_stop
     , t1.time_start_plan
     , t2.time_start_used
     , t1.time_stop_plan
     , t2.time_stop_used
from table1 t1
LEFT outer join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.number <= t2.number
order by ids, numbers
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e7140/12/0)**:

```
|  ids | numbers | diff_start | diff_stop |      time_start_plan |      time_start_used |       time_stop_plan |       time_stop_used |
|------|---------|------------|-----------|----------------------|----------------------|----------------------|----------------------|
|  965 |       1 |         34 |        21 | 2017-09-11T00:00:00Z | 2017-09-11T00:34:41Z | 2017-09-11T00:15:00Z | 2017-09-11T00:36:34Z |
|  965 |       1 |        153 |       141 | 2017-09-11T00:00:00Z | 2017-09-11T02:33:00Z | 2017-09-11T00:15:00Z | 2017-09-11T02:36:26Z |
|  965 |       1 |        264 |       252 | 2017-09-11T00:00:00Z | 2017-09-11T04:24:17Z | 2017-09-11T00:15:00Z | 2017-09-11T04:27:42Z |
|  965 |       1 |        366 |       363 | 2017-09-11T00:00:00Z | 2017-09-11T06:06:02Z | 2017-09-11T00:15:00Z | 2017-09-11T06:18:19Z |
|  965 |       1 |       1361 |      1347 | 2017-09-11T00:00:00Z | 2017-09-11T22:41:02Z | 2017-09-11T00:15:00Z | 2017-09-11T22:42:06Z |
|  965 |       2 |         78 |        71 | 2017-09-11T01:15:00Z | 2017-09-11T02:33:00Z | 2017-09-11T01:25:00Z | 2017-09-11T02:36:26Z |
|  965 |       2 |        189 |       182 | 2017-09-11T01:15:00Z | 2017-09-11T04:24:17Z | 2017-09-11T01:25:00Z | 2017-09-11T04:27:42Z |
|  965 |       2 |        291 |       293 | 2017-09-11T01:15:00Z | 2017-09-11T06:06:02Z | 2017-09-11T01:25:00Z | 2017-09-11T06:18:19Z |
|  965 |       2 |       1286 |      1277 | 2017-09-11T01:15:00Z | 2017-09-11T22:41:02Z | 2017-09-11T01:25:00Z | 2017-09-11T22:42:06Z |
|  965 |       3 |        104 |        97 | 2017-09-11T02:40:00Z | 2017-09-11T04:24:17Z | 2017-09-11T02:50:00Z | 2017-09-11T04:27:42Z |
|  965 |       3 |        206 |       208 | 2017-09-11T02:40:00Z | 2017-09-11T06:06:02Z | 2017-09-11T02:50:00Z | 2017-09-11T06:18:19Z |
|  965 |       3 |       1201 |      1192 | 2017-09-11T02:40:00Z | 2017-09-11T22:41:02Z | 2017-09-11T02:50:00Z | 2017-09-11T22:42:06Z |
|  965 |       4 |        106 |       108 | 2017-09-11T04:20:00Z | 2017-09-11T06:06:02Z | 2017-09-11T04:30:00Z | 2017-09-11T06:18:19Z |
|  965 |       4 |       1101 |      1092 | 2017-09-11T04:20:00Z | 2017-09-11T22:41:02Z | 2017-09-11T04:30:00Z | 2017-09-11T22:42:06Z |
| 1122 |       1 |         10 |        -5 | 2017-09-11T00:05:00Z | 2017-09-11T00:15:12Z | 2017-09-11T00:20:00Z | 2017-09-11T00:15:32Z |
| 1122 |       1 |         62 |        66 | 2017-09-11T00:05:00Z | 2017-09-11T01:07:56Z | 2017-09-11T00:20:00Z | 2017-09-11T01:26:57Z |
| 1122 |       1 |        104 |        91 | 2017-09-11T00:05:00Z | 2017-09-11T01:49:02Z | 2017-09-11T00:20:00Z | 2017-09-11T01:51:13Z |
| 1122 |       1 |        208 |       194 | 2017-09-11T00:05:00Z | 2017-09-11T03:33:50Z | 2017-09-11T00:20:00Z | 2017-09-11T03:34:17Z |
| 1122 |       1 |        242 |       229 | 2017-09-11T00:05:00Z | 2017-09-11T04:07:59Z | 2017-09-11T00:20:00Z | 2017-09-11T04:09:10Z |
| 1122 |       1 |        346 |       334 | 2017-09-11T00:05:00Z | 2017-09-11T05:51:23Z | 2017-09-11T00:20:00Z | 2017-09-11T05:54:22Z |
| 1122 |       2 |        -13 |        -4 | 2017-09-11T01:20:00Z | 2017-09-11T01:07:56Z | 2017-09-11T01:30:00Z | 2017-09-11T01:26:57Z |
| 1122 |       2 |         29 |        21 | 2017-09-11T01:20:00Z | 2017-09-11T01:49:02Z | 2017-09-11T01:30:00Z | 2017-09-11T01:51:13Z |
| 1122 |       2 |        133 |       124 | 2017-09-11T01:20:00Z | 2017-09-11T03:33:50Z | 2017-09-11T01:30:00Z | 2017-09-11T03:34:17Z |
| 1122 |       2 |        167 |       159 | 2017-09-11T01:20:00Z | 2017-09-11T04:07:59Z | 2017-09-11T01:30:00Z | 2017-09-11T04:09:10Z |
| 1122 |       2 |        271 |       264 | 2017-09-11T01:20:00Z | 2017-09-11T05:51:23Z | 2017-09-11T01:30:00Z | 2017-09-11T05:54:22Z |
| 1122 |       3 |        -81 |       -89 | 2017-09-11T03:10:00Z | 2017-09-11T01:49:02Z | 2017-09-11T03:20:00Z | 2017-09-11T01:51:13Z |
| 1122 |       3 |         23 |        14 | 2017-09-11T03:10:00Z | 2017-09-11T03:33:50Z | 2017-09-11T03:20:00Z | 2017-09-11T03:34:17Z |
| 1122 |       3 |         57 |        49 | 2017-09-11T03:10:00Z | 2017-09-11T04:07:59Z | 2017-09-11T03:20:00Z | 2017-09-11T04:09:10Z |
| 1122 |       3 |        161 |       154 | 2017-09-11T03:10:00Z | 2017-09-11T05:51:23Z | 2017-09-11T03:20:00Z | 2017-09-11T05:54:22Z |
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need a FULL OUTER JOIN like this example also available here at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e7140/11)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([ID] int, [number] int, [time_start_plan] datetime, [time_stop_plan] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([ID], [number], [time_start_plan], [time_stop_plan])
VALUES
    (965, 1, '2017-09-11 00:00:00.000', '2017-09-11 00:15:00.000'),
    (965, 2, '2017-09-11 01:15:00.000', '2017-09-11 01:25:00.000'),
    (965, 3, '2017-09-11 02:40:00.000', '2017-09-11 02:50:00.000'),
    (965, 4, '2017-09-11 04:20:00.000', '2017-09-11 04:30:00.000'),
    (1122, 1, '2017-09-11 00:05:00.000', '2017-09-11 00:20:00.000'),
    (1122, 2, '2017-09-11 01:20:00.000', '2017-09-11 01:30:00.000'),
    (1122, 3, '2017-09-11 03:10:00.000', '2017-09-11 03:20:00.000');


CREATE TABLE Table2
    ([ID] int, [number] int, [time_start_used] datetime, [time_stop_used] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Table2
    ([ID], [number], [time_start_used], [time_stop_used])
VALUES
    (965, 1, '2017-09-11 00:34:41.000', '2017-09-11 00:36:34.000'),
    (965, 2, '2017-09-11 02:33:00.000', '2017-09-11 02:36:26.000'),
    (965, 3, '2017-09-11 04:24:17.000', '2017-09-11 04:27:42.000'),
    (965, 4, '2017-09-11 06:06:02.000', '2017-09-11 06:18:19.000'),
    (965, 5, '2017-09-11 22:41:02.000', '2017-09-11 22:42:06.000'),
    (1122, 1, '2017-09-11 00:15:12.000', '2017-09-11 00:15:32.000'),
    (1122, 2, '2017-09-11 01:07:56.000', '2017-09-11 01:26:57.000'),
    (1122, 3, '2017-09-11 01:49:02.000', '2017-09-11 01:51:13.000'),
    (1122, 4, '2017-09-11 03:33:50.000', '2017-09-11 03:34:17.000'),
    (1122, 5, '2017-09-11 04:07:59.000', '2017-09-11 04:09:10.000'),
    (1122, 6, '2017-09-11 05:51:23.000', '2017-09-11 05:54:22.000')
;
```

**Query**:

```
select
       coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) ids
     , coalesce(t1.number, t2.number) numbers
     , datediff(minute,t1.time_start_plan, t2.time_start_used) diff_start
     , datediff(minute,t1.time_stop_plan, t2.time_stop_used) diff_stop
     , t1.time_start_plan
     , t2.time_start_used
     , t1.time_stop_plan
     , t2.time_stop_used
from table1 t1
full outer join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.number = t2.number
order by ids, numbers
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e7140/11/0)**:

```
|  ids | numbers | diff_start | diff_stop |      time_start_plan |      time_start_used |       time_stop_plan |       time_stop_used |
|------|---------|------------|-----------|----------------------|----------------------|----------------------|----------------------|
|  965 |       1 |         34 |        21 | 2017-09-11T00:00:00Z | 2017-09-11T00:34:41Z | 2017-09-11T00:15:00Z | 2017-09-11T00:36:34Z |
|  965 |       2 |         78 |        71 | 2017-09-11T01:15:00Z | 2017-09-11T02:33:00Z | 2017-09-11T01:25:00Z | 2017-09-11T02:36:26Z |
|  965 |       3 |        104 |        97 | 2017-09-11T02:40:00Z | 2017-09-11T04:24:17Z | 2017-09-11T02:50:00Z | 2017-09-11T04:27:42Z |
|  965 |       4 |        106 |       108 | 2017-09-11T04:20:00Z | 2017-09-11T06:06:02Z | 2017-09-11T04:30:00Z | 2017-09-11T06:18:19Z |
|  965 |       5 |     (null) |    (null) |               (null) | 2017-09-11T22:41:02Z |               (null) | 2017-09-11T22:42:06Z |
| 1122 |       1 |         10 |        -5 | 2017-09-11T00:05:00Z | 2017-09-11T00:15:12Z | 2017-09-11T00:20:00Z | 2017-09-11T00:15:32Z |
| 1122 |       2 |        -13 |        -4 | 2017-09-11T01:20:00Z | 2017-09-11T01:07:56Z | 2017-09-11T01:30:00Z | 2017-09-11T01:26:57Z |
| 1122 |       3 |        -81 |       -89 | 2017-09-11T03:10:00Z | 2017-09-11T01:49:02Z | 2017-09-11T03:20:00Z | 2017-09-11T01:51:13Z |
| 1122 |       4 |     (null) |    (null) |               (null) | 2017-09-11T03:33:50Z |               (null) | 2017-09-11T03:34:17Z |
| 1122 |       5 |     (null) |    (null) |               (null) | 2017-09-11T04:07:59Z |               (null) | 2017-09-11T04:09:10Z |
| 1122 |       6 |     (null) |    (null) |               (null) | 2017-09-11T05:51:23Z |               (null) | 2017-09-11T05:54:22Z |
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I didn't precise, what I need to compare is: each row form table1 with every rowrs on table2 (the same ID). The reason is that on the t2 I  could have a few matching rows f.eg. employee should go on break at 00:15-00:30 and went on 00:16-00:18 and 00:19-00:31,both will be correct planed break match with used but t2 has two matching rows.

Comment: then try it **WITHOUT** using the join condition t1.number=t2.number but you will get a lot more rows and a lot more irrelevant results too.

Comment: You could try `AND t2.number >= t1.number` **instead of** `AND t2.number = t1.number`

Comment: Your script is ok, thanks for help. On this level I don't need the number column, main problem is to compare every row by ID not 'number'. However, may be there is better way to find difference between planned break and used, I'm still looking for the best (efficient) solution.

Comment: and I'm hoping for the best (most succinct) explanation of your need. I you provide (manually if necessary) the "expected result" arising from your sample data. Without that we are left guessing, no matter how many words you use.